# Email to Salesforce question

Tags: emailtosalesforce

I am wondering if it is possible to forward an email into Salesforce that I received from a contact and have the email associated with the contact's record.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to do so, including using Outlook to directly attach records, or email-to-salesforce to associate records by sending an email. You'll want to identify how you'd like this to work, then look up the appropriate help topic on [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/), such as "email-to-salesforce" or "Lightning for Outlook".

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with Email to Salesforce.

If you configure Email to Salesforce to associate emails to matching leads or contacts, Salesforce searches the To and CC fields for the email addresses of your leads or contacts. If any leads or contacts are found, Salesforce saves the email to the Activity History related list on the appropriate record.

If Salesforce can’t match any email addresses for recipients that appear in the To and CC fields of emails that you add to Salesforce, the My Unresolved Items page displays one row for each email.

It is also possible to relate the email to a specific record by including the record Id in the subject or body before forwarding.

Here you can read more about how email to Salesforce works:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc.htm&type=5